# NoMethodError in PostsController#create undefined method `text' for #<Post:0x007f99088407f8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I've been having trouble getting past this error. It says that it 'text' is undefined.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.save # (this line is highlighted in the error)
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```

This worked fine when I had originally 'rails generate' the scaffold with title:string body:text.

I've been stuck on this problem all day. Suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: When you generated the scaffold did you do a `rake db:migrate` after? Also do you have the stack trace for the error

Comment: You column name is `body`. Your view is trying to set the column `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is accessing the attribute `text`, but it should be `body`